# express-validator always invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im building a project on the latest version of `nodejs` and `express` I have a basic site setup im just trying to make the user authentication work(learning from [this](https://stackskills.com/courses/learn-nodejs-by-building-10-projects))

but no matter what I do I cannot get the `express-validator` to validate it will just always be invalid

```
validator deprecated you tried to validate a undefined but this library (validator.js) validates strings only. Please update your code as this will be an error soon. node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:338:41
```

This is the only error i get but im not sure what to do as everything seems to matchup with the github docs

### app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Handle File Uploads
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave:true
}));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift() 
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

### routes/users.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{
   'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{
   'title': 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register',function(req, res, next){
 // Get Form Values
 var name = req.body.name;
 var email = req.body.email;
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var password2 = req.body.password2;

 // Check for Image Field
 if(req.files && req.files.profileImage){
  console.log('Uploading File...');

  // File Info
  var profileImageOriginalName  = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
  var profileImageName    = req.files.profileimage.name;
  var profileImageMime    = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
  var profileImagePath    = req.files.profileimage.path;
  var profileImageExt    = req.files.profileimage.extension;
  var profileImageSize    = req.files.profileimage.size;
 } else {
  // Set a Default Image
  var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
 }

 // Form Validation
 req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
 req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

 // Check for errors
 var errors = req.validationErrors();

 if(errors){
  res.render('register',{
   errors: errors,
   name: name,
   email: email,
   username: username,
   password: password,
   password2: password2
  });
 } else {
  var newUser = new User({
   name: name,
   email: email,
   username: username,
   password: password,
   profileimage: profileImageName
  });

   // Create User
 User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(user);
 });


  // Success Message
  req.flash('success','You are now registered and may log in');

  res.location('/');
  res.redirect('/');
 }
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 function(username, password, done){
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
   if(err) throw err;
   if(!user){
    console.log('Unknown User');
    return done(null, false,{message: 'Unknown User'});
   }

   User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(isMatch){
     return done(null, user);
    } else {
     console.log('Invalid Password');
     return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
    }
   });
  });
 }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash:'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res){
 console.log('Authentication Successful');
 req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
 res.redirect('/');
});


module.exports = router;
```

### views/register.jade

```html
extends layout

block content
 h1 Register
 p Please register using the form below
 ul.errors
  if errors
   each error, i in errors
    li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
 form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
  .form-group
   label Name
   input.form-control(name='name', type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
  .form-group
   label Email
   input.form-control(name='email', type='email',placeholder='Enter Email')
  .form-group
   label Username
   input.form-control(name='username', type='text',placeholder='Username')
  .form-group
   label Password
   input.form-control(name='password', type='password',placeholder='Enter Password')
  .form-group
   label Confirm Password
   input.form-control(name='password2', type='password',placeholder='Confirm Password')
  .form-group
   label Profile Image
   input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
  input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit',value='Register')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.notEmpty()` check with `isEmpty()`

Source : [ValidateJS](https://validatejs.org/)

```
isEmpty : validate.isEmpty(value)
Check if the given value is non empty. The following value are considered empty:

null
undefined
Empty strings
Whitespace only strings
Empty arrays
Empty objects
```

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i dont think this is the same library i am using https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

Comment: Yea you are correct, but express-validator uses Validator.js (https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/blob/master/lib/express_validator.js)